# Expandable UITableView with moving rows between sections buggy footer problem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make an expandable tableview. Here I didn't use *headers* and made all of those section stuff using rows. In here I've found a bad behaviour that blocks my move operations. As you see in gif, i added height on footer sections to show what is really happening. I don't want any border in my application between sections. As you see, I want to move rows into upper section if it is upper than 'Done' section text. How can I achieve those purpose?

Problem Demo: [https://i.imgur.com/VIMf5sb.gif](https://i.imgur.com/VIMf5sb.mp4)

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(sourceIndexPath)
    print(destinationIndexPath) }
```

In the buggy situation destinationIndexPath section is 2 and row is 0. So I believe my code does not contain any code error. How can I fix that UX problem when there is no border between sections?

Comment: MP4 cannot be downloaded，any gif？

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/VIMf5sb.gif) I edited the question.